# Is Ext group compatible with base field extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ be a $k$-algebra. Let $M$ and $N$ be two left $A$-modules then we could consider the Ext group $\mathrm{Ext}^i_A(M,N)$ which is actually a $k$-vector space.

Now let $l/k$ be a field extension and we consider $A_l$, $M_l$, and $N_l$ be the base-change algebras and modules, i.e. $A_l=A\otimes_kl$, etc. We can also consider $\mathrm{Ext}^i_{A_l}(M_l,N_l)$.

My question:

> Is it true that $\mathrm{Ext}^i_{A_l}(M_l,N_l)\cong \mathrm{Ext}^i_A(M,N)\otimes_kl$ for any $A$, $M$, $N$ and $i$?

Comment: It depends on the argument: all you have to do is consider the case when $N=0$ and extend by $\delta$-universality. In that case, you want finitely presented stuff, I think.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff You mean $N=0$ or $N=k$?

Comment: Sorry, I mean $i=0$, the cohomological index. That is, check what are the conditions that ensure that the canonical map
$$ \hom_{A_\ell}(M_\ell,N_\ell) \longrightarrow \hom_A(M,N)_\ell$$
is an isomorphism. In general, this isn't an isomorphism!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I see. What is the typical conter-example for the last isomorphism?

Comment: There is a chapter in Bourbaki's algebra solely dedicated to this question. Check it out.